# Query for Programs Returns Security Exception

Tags: android, android-contentresolver, android-tv

When I try to query the Programs database by anything other than channel or program id I get the following exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Selection not allowed for content://android.media.tv/program
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:421)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:530)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:472)
```

Note that I can add and delete programs, so I think permissions are correctly set in the manifest file.

The following sample code tries to query by program title, but the above exception is thrown.

```
Uri uri = TvContract.Programs.CONTENT_URI;

Cursor cursor = null;
try {
    String mSelectionClause = TvContract.Programs.COLUMN_TITLE + " = ?";
    String[] mSelectionArgs = { "Test title" };
    cursor = resolver.query(uri, Program.PROJECTION, mSelectionClause, mSelectionArgs, null);
    if (cursor == null || cursor.getCount() == 0) {
        Log.d(TAG, "No programs found for 'Test title'");
        return programs;
    }
    Log.d(TAG, cursor.getCount() + " programs found for 'Test tilte'");
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Unable to get programs for 'Test title'", e);
} finally {
    if (cursor != null) {
        cursor.close();
    }
}
```

Is it not possible to query by any column?

Answer (score 2):

The TvProvider is not open for selections. You can add/update/delete but you cannot create custom queries. You will need to use the TvContractCompat to build your query URIs and evaluate the results.

```
context.getContentResolver()
    .query(TvContractCompat.buildChannelUri(channelId), null, null, null, null);
```

or for programs

```
context.getContentResolver()
    .query(TvContractCompat.buildProgramsUriForChannel(channelId), null, null, null, null);
```

and for a specific program

```
context.getContentResolver()
    .query(TvContractCompat.buildProgramUri(programId), null, null, null, null);
```

For your example you should query for the programs in your channels and search for the title.

```
try (Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver()
                      .query(
                TvContractCompat.buildProgramsUriForChannel(channelId),
                null, null, null, null)) {
    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToNext()) {
        Program program = Program.fromCursor(cursor);
        if( "Test Title".equals(program.getTitle()) {
            // Do stuff...
        }
    }
}
```

Reference:
https://developer.android.com/training/tv/discovery/recommendations-channel.html#best_practices

Comment: I see that that the article in the link you provided mentions that "WHERE clauses are not allowed". Why is that though? It's very restrictive. Having to go through all channel's programs every time you want to access a specific program is very slow!

Comment: @vas Since multiple apps can have channels in the Tv Provider, the provider tries to limit each app to it's own sandbox of data. 

Ideally if you want to query a specific program, you should query by an identifier not a title. Titles can be translated into different languages and do not make great keys. This is one reason why the Tv Provider only allows queries by id. 

You can set a projection on your query so that you do not get all of the metadata back in the results. 

What is your particular use case where the title is the key? I am curious to understand better.